# How to render the javascript frontend application, in rails json API architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails app, with front end on martyjs/reactjs. 
I've set a route that matches every pattern, so the user can follow any link deep in my reactjs app.
I am implementing login/logout and I've came up with a problem. 
`In my application_controller.rb` I've set up a filter:

```
  before_action :authenticated_account?
  def authenticated_account?
        customer = User::Customer.find_by_session_token cookies.signed[:session_token]
        if customer.verify_session!(cookies.signed[:session_token],request.remote_ip ) then else resp = Response.new("Not authorized", nil, 401) end
         return respond resp if resp
      end
```

But rightly, this deny my interface to render, since the server receive a JSON with the message.
This is a good response when my app it is already loaded, because my app intercept gracefully the 401 code.

But I am not find out a soluton for rendering my js app and respond to the code if a user open a window and go to a link directly deep in my reactjs app.

Comment: you can try using request.xhr? to check it js request instead of json and then redirect using js.erb

Comment: I think the solution must be on the rails side. I am missing surely something simple

Comment: i gave the solution which is used on rails side to detect if request is json/js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I've said, I knew that I was missing something. I've simply dedicated a controller action to the render of the html page with the onePageApplication, and skipped the authentication check on that.

So, recap:

To serve a onePageApp with rails.

set the route for your api calls:

```
namespace :api do
    ...
  end
```

and the route for serving the UI:

```
scope "/", :format => false do

    get "/" => "application#uiserve"
    get "/*path" => "application#uiserve"

    root :to => "application#index"

  end
```

In this way, when a user digit a deep link in my app, it will always be matched, and served with the HTML page with the JS code.

The requests that the app will make, will be under the namespace `:api` so it will be routed correctly